# Can helicopters have engines running while rotor blade stays stationary?

Tags: helicopter

So, I was skiing sometime ago, and unfortunately, another skier got injured. So, a heli was flown up to get the injured skier. The rotor blades were stationary, but I still heard some sort of engine like sound. Does anyone know any helicopters capable of doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, many helicopters (but not all) can do this. There are 2 main methods:

- a clutch between engine and rotor system
- for turbines only: a [rotor brake](http://navyaviation.tpub.com/14018/css/Rotor-Brake-System-403.htm) on the engine output shaft. The engine contains a [free turbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-turbine_turboshaft) (i.e. a turbine stage that isn't attached to the compressor) that drives the rotor system. If you brake this shaft, the engine can run without spinning the rotors.

Comment: I can't seem to find any of these of the Bell 412 or AS350 for example. Any documentation?

Comment: Bell 412 engines: https://www.euravia.aero/engine-detail/pt6t-3df

Comment: Also, is there a term for this method of stopping blades while engine is running?

Comment: so technically I can run the engines at idle, and apply rotor brake? And does that mean that the 412 has no clutches?

Comment: The brake is called a rotor brake. The procedure would depend on the helicopter, but generally, yes I'd expect you can idle the engine and apply the rotor brake. Some rotor brakes are automatic, I see.

Comment: I guess this deos not apply to the Bell 412, just checked and the manual said that the brakes must not be on when engines are on.

Comment: It could also have been an APU running rather than the main engine.

Comment: You can even run free turbine turboprops like the PT-6 at ground idle while holding the propeller still by hand.  This is done in service.  You must not allow it to move however because if you let the free turbine start to spin the torque builds rapidly and you'll have to let it go and get out of the way.

Comment: I can't help but wonder how big a starter you'd need for a helicopter if you needed to spin the rotor blades too.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield not for the bell 412. It doesn't have an AOU to my knowledge

Comment: In all the helicopters I know the rotor brake is intended to slow down the rotor AFTER engine shutdown. There is also an RPM limit for applying the rotor brake, usually not more than 50% of the flight RPM. Applying the rotor brake on a helicopter with running engines, even at idle, would be spectacular and expensive.